# Clear data of Flutter for Desktop (Windows) application

Tags: windows, flutter, caching, desktop, flutter2.0

I am developing an app for Windows Desktop, using Flutter 2.0.
How can I clear app data and make it as it was at day zero, remove all caches, remove any signed accounts, ... just like Clear Data in Android.